# How to display image from Wordpress in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code

```
return Post(
      id: json['id'],

      title: json['title']['rendered'],
      content: json['content']['rendered'],
      date: json['date'] != null
        ? json['date'].toString().replaceFirst('T', ' ')
        : null,
      image: json['_links']['wp:featuredmedia'] != null
        ? json['_links']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['source_url']
        : null,
      excerpt: json['excerpt']['rendered'],
      author: json['author'].toString(),
    );
  }
```

And then i use

```
post.image != null
              ? Image.network(post.image)
```

But i dont have image in my App. Mistake: Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.
How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you add your image source url ? the issue might be linked to the file url

Comment: Yes. The problem with URL.

Comment: Thats my link from Debugger
http://cs48365.tmweb.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/media/13

Comment: you should probably parse the image url from the `media_details` instead of `_links`

Comment: Now this mistake:

Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("wp:featuredmedia"))

Answer (score 0):

No, you assign the link of the wp:featuredmedia directly to the image property and then render that using the Image.network() widget wherever you want.

Just see where's your featured media link is stored in your JSON response from the API. Go through the JSON tree and assign that value.

This will work.

Comment: If i will do that in this way i will have error message (Type String is not a subtype of type int). This message i take after my ['href'].

Comment: Thats my full way to my image
['_links']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['href']['media_details']['file']

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
image: json["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["source_url"],
```

it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the following base link

```
https://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

The fix is to change the base URL as follows

```
https://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
```

And then using the following:

```
image: json["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["source_url"]
```